# Remove elements from Numpy array until y has equivalent elements in each value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `y` composed of `0` and `1`, but at a different frequency.

For example:

```
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

And I have an array `x` of the same length.

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

The idea is to filter out elements until there are the same number of `0` and `1`.

A valid solution would be to remove index 5:

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6])
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

A naive method I can think of is to get the difference between the value frequency of y (in this case `4-3=1`) create a mask for `y == 1` and switch random elements from `True` to `False` until the difference is `0`. Then create a mask for `y == 0`, do a `OR` between them and apply it to both `x` and `y`.

This doesn't really seem the best "python/numpy way" of doing it though.

Any suggestions? Something like randomly select `n` elements from the highest count, where `n` is the count of the lowest value.

If this is easier with pandas then that would work for me too.

Naive algorithm assuming 1 > 0:

```
mask_pos = y == 1
mask_neg = y == 0

pos = len(y[mask_pos])
neg = len(y[mask_neg])

diff = pos-neg

while diff > 0:
    rand = np.random.randint(0, len(y))

    if mask_pos[rand] == True:
        mask_pos[rand] = False
        diff -= 1

mask_final = mask_pos | mask_neg

y_new = y[mask_final]
x_new = x[mask_final]
```

This naive algorithm is really slow

Comment: So `y` always contains exclusively `0` or `1`? That is, you are not considering cases where `y` has more different values and you need to balance all of them right?

Comment: Yes, only 0 and 1 is necessary

Comment: Is this a representation of an imbalanced dataset? If yes you can do this with the `imblearn.undersampling` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that with NumPy is this:

```py
import numpy as np

# Makes a mask to balance ones and zeros
def balance_binary_mask(binary_array):
    binary_array = np.asarray(binary_array).ravel()
    # Count number of ones
    z = np.count_nonzero(binary_array)
    # If there are less ones than zeros
    if z <= len(binary_array) // 2:
        # Invert the array
        binary_array = ~binary_array
    # Find ones
    idx = np.nonzero(binary_array)[0]
    # Number of elements to remove
    rem = 2 * len(idx) - len(binary_array)
    # Pick random indices to remove
    rem_idx = np.random.choice(idx, size=rem, replace=False)
    # Make mask
    mask = np.ones_like(binary_array, dtype=bool)
    # Mask elements to remove
    mask[rem_idx] = False
    return mask

# Test
np.random.seed(0)
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
m = balance_binary_mask(y)
print(m)
# [ True  True  True  True False  True  True]
y = y[m]
x = x[m]
print(y)
# [0 0 1 1 1 0]
print(x)
# [0 1 2 3 5 6]
```